# There was error uploading Android App Bundle. Try again later or contact Google Play developer suport if the error persists

Tags: android, android-studio, unity-game-engine, publishing

Developed a game in unity and build a signed app bundle in android studio. When I uploaded the app bundle to the play store I get that error. I have tried incognito mode, clear all cookies and history and even log out all my accounts, but still not able to upload the app bundle. I contacted google play developer support but they are taking too long than usual.

Comment: That can happen if the app bundle you're trying to upload has the same version code as an app bundle that has been already uploaded. Double check to see that it has a higher version code.

Comment: Make sure your key and password is correct.  I think this is a silent error...

Comment: I have the same problem with a super old APK and trying updating it with an AAB. Did you get this resolved?

Comment: As @JeanLuc, the same is happening to me since yesterday, with a bundle that usually uploads without issues. I tried incrementing the versionCode, because that was the cause of upload errors in the past, but to no avail this time. Seems to be a bug on Google's end. Reported and now awaiting their reply.

Comment: Same here. Google is investigating it.

Comment: I’ve found out the cause in our case: that was due to upgrading the Material Components library com.google.android.material:material from version 1.6.1 to version 1.7.0.

Comment: @S01ds We are using Unity and don't use the Material Component library. The technical team of Google is  investigating it, but sadly no result yet.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is actually related to one of the following
**code version,
key store or
app package name**

when i uploaded an app with changing all the previously mentioned it worked